# Undefined name 'widget'. Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name

Tags: flutter, dart

I've got this error msg when I wanna use widget. in my codes.
here are the codes:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:meals_recipes/models/meal.dart';
import 'package:meals_recipes/widgets/meal_item.dart';

class CategoryMealsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/categorymeals';
  final List<Meal> availableMeals;

  CategoryMealsScreen(this.availableMeals);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final routeArgs =
        ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String, String>;
    final categoryTitle = routeArgs['title'];
    final categoryId = routeArgs['id'];
    final displayedMeals = widget.availableMeals.where((meal) {
      return meal.categories.contains(categoryId);
    }).toList();

return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(categoryTitle!),
    ),
    body: ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
        return MealItem(
            duration: displayedMeals[index].duration,
            imageUrl: displayedMeals[index].imageUrl,
            title: displayedMeals[index].title,
            id: displayedMeals[index].id,
            affordability: displayedMeals[index].affordability,
            complexity: displayedMeals[index].complexity);
      },
      itemCount: displayedMeals.length,
    ));
```

}
}

Please help me out.
I see there are more useful codes using widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `CategoryMealsScreen` was supposed to be a `StatefulWidget`, so you can convert it to `StatefulWidget`:

```dart
class CategoryMealsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/categorymeals';
  final List<Meal> availableMeals;

  CategoryMealsScreen(this.availableMeals);

  @override
  State<CategoryMealsScreen> createState() => _CategoryMealsScreenState();
}

class _CategoryMealsScreenState extends State<CategoryMealsScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final routeArgs =
        ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String, String>;
    final categoryTitle = routeArgs['title'];
    final categoryId = routeArgs['id'];
    final displayedMeals = widget.availableMeals.where((meal) {
      return meal.categories.contains(categoryId);
    }).toList();

    return Scaffold(
      // ...
    );
  }
}
```

Or if you don't need `StatefulWidget`, you can just change this line:

```dart
final displayedMeals = widget.availableMeals.where((meal) {
```

to this:

```dart
final displayedMeals = availableMeals.where((meal) {
```